# How to animate a Path on a canvas using ObjectAnimator in Android

Tags: java

I am trying to draw a Rect, a Circle and another Rect using a path. 
Kind of like a long progress bar with a bump in the middle.

i have a Custom view and in onDraw(Canvas c) method, I simply have to do

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(0f, 0f);
path.addRect(rect1, Path.Direction.CW);
path.addArc(circle, -90, fillSweep);
path.addRect(rect2, Path.Direction.CW);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

The drawing is perfect. But I want it to animate as it's drawing the path. Like filling a gap hole.

My Question is: How do you animate a path in Android. Using something like the Object Property Animator. 
Something like:
  ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(theCustomView, "path", ...., ....);
       animator.start();

Please help.

All the examples out there are too complicated or don't do what I want it to. This should be very simple, but can't find a way to do this anywhere.

Thanks.